# Zero Vectors and Vector Spaces

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

In a solution guide I've read that $\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c \end{bmatrix} : a+b+c=2$ isn't a vector space because it doesn't have the zero vector. I'm not 100% sure why this is but I think it's because if you make $a, b, c=0$ you don't get $2$ which is what it's meant to be equal to? Is my thinking correct or not?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, the coordinate sum of the zero vector is not $2$, hence $0\not\in V$.

Comment: Yea, no 0 vector implies no neutral element so the vector space isn't a group with respect to edition

Comment: Correct. Out if interest it isn't closed with respect to addition either (and probably doesn't satisfy other axioms too!).

Comment: "Yea, no 0 vector implies no neutral element so the vector space isn't a group with respect to edition".  I wouldn't use the term "vector space" here!